# How to launch cgi script on remote via python

Tags: python, curl, https, cgi, python-2.6

I would like to know if there is a python alternative to following curl command:

```
curl https://$ip/some_folder/some_script.cgi -k -u $user:"$pass" --interface $some_ip --connect-timeout 20 --max-time 30 -s
```

Sorry if this question is too basic but i am a python noob.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially looking for the proper formulation of `httplib.HTTPSConnection(TheURL, [options])` in Python 2.6, or `urllib.request.urlopen(TheURL, [etc])` in Python 3.

HTTPSConnection is a class, not an event, so when you create it you will need to set it up the way you want according to whatever you were expecting from curl.

Here are the relevant docs for [Python2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/httplib.html) and [Python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html). Your -k option simply makes insecure HTTPS OK, and the user/pw thing will have to be done by handling the request or including it in the request, I believe.

Comment: @sztyrymytyry どういたしまして！ \(^.^)/